# aregexec matching with two data frames

Tags: regex, r, replace, vectorization

One is the target data frame (`targetframe`) and the other dataframe works as a library (`word.library`) with some key values. Then I need the following algorithm: The algorithm should look up an approximate match between `word.library$mainword` and `targetframe$words`. After figuring out the approximate match the substrings in targetframe$words should be replaced with `word.library$keyID`.

Here are the two data frames mentioned above:

```
tragetframe <- data.frame(words= c("This is sentence one with the important word",
                                 "This is sentence two with the inportant woord",
                                  "This is sentence three with crazy sayings" ))

word.library <- data.frame(mainword = c("important word",
                                        "crazy sayings"),
                           keyID = c("1001",
                                     "2001"))
```

Here is my solution which works.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(word.library)){
positions <- aregexec(word.library[i,1], tragetframe$words, max.distance = 0.1)
res <- regmatches(tragetframe$words, positions)
res[lengths(res)==0] <- "XXXX"  # deal with 0 length matches somehow
tragetframe$words <- Vectorize(gsub)(unlist(res), word.library[i,2], tragetframe$words)
tragetframe$words
}
```

However: I use a for loop which is not efficent (imagine I have two huge data frames). Has anyone an idea how to resovle this issue more efficiently?